# How to Convert string of multiple object to in array with different keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a string to multiple objects and I need to add this object in an array with different values. This data received from the cart so object can be 2,3,4...

exmaple:

```
{"hidden_product_name":"productA","productId":"120","product_sku":"","quantity":"2","hidden_unit_price":"500","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"1000"},{"hidden_product_name":"productB","productId":"127","product_sku":"","quantity":"1","hidden_unit_price":"300","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"300"}
```

this is a full string of two objects and I want the output like this.

Desire output:

```
[{"hidden_product_name":"productA","productId":"120","product_sku":"","quantity":"2","hidden_unit_price":"500","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"1000"},{"hidden_product_name":"productB","productId":"127","product_sku":"","quantity":"1","hidden_unit_price":"300","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"300"}]
```

How can I do this please help...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried split(), JSON.parse(), arrya.push(); but don;t get my result

Comment: Given your example `JSON.parse('[' + exampleString + ']')` should already be sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the best and easiest way to resolve this problem...

```
data = '{"hidden_product_name":"productA","productId":"120","product_sku":"","quantity":"2","hidden_unit_price":"500","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"1000"},{"hidden_product_name":"productB","productId":"127","product_sku":"","quantity":"1","hidden_unit_price":"300","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"300"}';

data2 = '['+data+']';
```

then data2 will return:

```
[{"hidden_product_name":"productA","productId":"120","product_sku":"","quantity":"2","hidden_unit_price":"500","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"1000"},{"hidden_product_name":"productB","productId":"127","product_sku":"","quantity":"1","hidden_unit_price":"300","hidden_total":"1300","total_pr_price":"300"}]
```